# plsql method to unzip file and leave resutl in same directory

Tags: oracle, plsql, unzip

Does anyone have a method within an Oracle procedure to unzip a file and leave the resulting contents (.txt file) in the same directory.

I am unable to use the very fine Oracle methodolgy of creating a Java package and using that to call the OS unzip utility due to local rules.  I have wondered about UTL_COMPRESS but read of issues unzipping files created by OS utilities and also the example I see unzip to a blob. I require the test file to be extracted to the OS file-system.

Comment: I'd try and change the rules so you can use java, much easier.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405676/zip-using-oracle-stored-procedure

Comment: @Karl - What, exactly, is the rule?  Are you prevented from calling out to the operating system?  Or are you prevented from using a Java stored procedure?  Exactly what format is the file you are trying to process?  Is it a ZIP file?  Or GZIP?

Comment: I am unable to use Java to access the server 'as it is a security hole'.  And as a contractor on a short contract I havae no hope of changing the rules.  But @Eggi's answer gives me something to play with.  Thanks to all.