# How to zip .csv file and attach in email Oracle plsql without using Java

Tags: sql, database, oracle, email, plsql

I am using Oracle 11.1
I have this plsql block which sends perfectly fine email with .csv attachment.

But I want to zip it and send. When I change the file extension as .zip, email comes fine as Report.zip ,but I cannot open the zip file, it says corrupted.
How do I compress?

```
DECLARE
    p_email   email%ROWTYPE;
    p_subject VARCHAR2(255)  := 'Weekly Report';
    p_message CLOB;
    l_mailhost VARCHAR2(255) := 'localhost';
    l_mail_conn utl_smtp.connection;

    v_add_src  VARCHAR2(4000);
    v_addr     VARCHAR2(4000);
    slen NUMBER := 1;

    crlf VARCHAR2(2)  := chr(13)||chr(10);
    v_date VARCHAR2(15) := TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE) -1,'MM_DD_YYYY');

/*Table header in attachment*/
v_col VARCHAR2(32000):= 'START_DATE'||CHR(166)||'END_DATE'||CHR(166)||'NAME'||crlf;

    CURSOR cur_query
    IS
    SELECT  
        START_DATE, END_DATE, NAME FROM TESTING

    BEGIN
    --SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE) -1,'MM_DD_YYYY') INTO v_date FROM dual;
     SELECT * INTO p_email FROM email WHERE module_name = 'REPORT';
          p_message:= 
            '<html>
                 <BODY>
                 <P> <font color="black",font face ="arial",font size ="2.5">
                Hello All, <br/><br/>
                Attached weekly report <br/>
                <br/>Thank You
                 </P>
                </BODY>
            </html>';

            l_mail_conn := utl_smtp.open_connection(l_mailhost, 25);
            utl_smtp.helo(l_mail_conn, l_mailhost);
            utl_smtp.mail(l_mail_conn, p_email.sender);

            IF(INSTR(p_email.recipients,',') = 0) THEN
                utl_smtp.rcpt(l_mail_conn, p_email.recipients);
            ELSE
            v_add_src := p_email.recipients || ',';
                WHILE(INSTR(v_add_src,',',slen) > 0) LOOP
                v_addr := SUBSTR(v_add_src, slen, INSTR(SUBSTR(v_add_src, slen),',')-1);
                slen := slen+INSTR(SUBSTR(v_add_src, slen),',');
                 --Dbms_Output.put_line('rcpt ' || v_addr);
                utl_smtp.rcpt(l_mail_conn, v_addr);
                END LOOP;

            END IF; 

            utl_smtp.open_data(l_mail_conn );
            utl_smtp.write_data(l_mail_conn,
             'MIME-VERSION: 1.0' || crlf ||
             'FROM: '   || p_email.sender || crlf ||
             'Subject: '|| p_subject || crlf ||
             'TO: '     || p_email.recipients || crlf || 
             'CONTENT-TYPE: multipart/mixed;' || crlf ||
             ' boundary="---YOURBOUNDARY"' || crlf ||crlf);
   -- Email body
            utl_smtp.write_data(l_mail_conn, '-----YOURBOUNDARY'||crlf);
            utl_smtp.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Type: text/html' || crlf);
            utl_smtp.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit' || crlf || crlf);
            utl_smtp.write_data(l_mail_conn, p_message||crlf);
    -- begin the attachment

            utl_smtp.write_data(l_mail_conn, '-----YOURBOUNDARY'||crlf);
            utl_smtp.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Type: text/plain;'||crlf); 
            utl_smtp.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit' || crlf);
           --utl_smtp.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Mime-Type: application/zip' || crlf);
            utl_smtp.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Disposition: attachment;'|| crlf);
            utl_smtp.write_data(l_mail_conn, ' filename="Report||.csv"'||crlf||crlf);
            utl_smtp.write_data(l_mail_conn,v_col);
          FOR rec IN cur_query
           LOOP
              utl_smtp.write_data(l_mail_conn, rec.start_date||CHR(166)||rec.end_date||CHR(166)||rec.NAME||||crlf);
           END LOOP;

        utl_smtp.close_data(l_mail_conn );
        utl_smtp.quit(l_mail_conn);

       EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('ERROR: '|| SQLCODE ||'Err Msg :'||SQLERRM);

     END;
```

Comment: This may help with how to zip in PL/SQL: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2192274

Comment: Why don't you want to use Java? And can you use [`utl_compress`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_compr.htm), or does it need to be a format that doesn't support? ([This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4405676) might be related, but not quite a duplicate).

Answer (score 1):

In the message section where you're transferring the .csv file you've got the MIME Content-Type set to "text/plain". When you change the file name to Report.zip you need to change the Content-Type to "application/zip". Hopefully this will fix things up for you.

Share and enjoy.